# Models responsability

Tags: laravel

I have a doub about Laravel. The models are used to define the relationships between the models like hasMany, belongsTo, etc. Also the models are used to define the fillable fields. But he models are only for that? Because I already check some examples that it seems that some queries are executed in the models instead of the controller so Im not understanding if the models should also have the querying of the relationships or not. Can you give a help to understand better what is the correct use of models (what should be placed in the models)?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "*if the models should also have the querying of the relationships or not*"?

Comment: Model is upper layer of controller, if anything is related to other than than current module you can put it in model because model are inherited frequently.

Comment: Thanks, if the query of the relationships should be in the models or is in the controller, or if depends and can be in controller but also in models.

Comment: You would usually define the relationship in the model and then get the data in the controller. You can define scopes in the model if you have a long query or just something that you use a lot throughout your application but that's not essential. Can you give an example of what of what you're wondering about?

Answer (score 0):

Its same way to execute queries on model or controller. Written queries in model make your controller more clean. We can write mutator, accessor or query scope in eloquent model. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

You can refer this documentation, it's quite helpful if you want to know deep basics and responsibilities about particular part in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Models are mostly used to make an outlook of the data i.e what fields are going to be saved in the database and we also use it to associate the relationships with other related data as you already know but we also use it to alter the values that are either going in/out of the data base which you can check in the documentation in link bellow https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators
the main purpose is to divide the code between controller and model (were it best fit to be)